# Ninject ASP.NET MVC4: “System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have installed Ninject through Nuget which includes Ninject, Ninject.Web.Common, Ninject.Web.Mvc(3). I now have a an issue where trying to use a service registered in NinjectWebCommon's RegisterServices does not work and I get the error above. This worked previously so I must have done something that messed the whole thing up somewhere. Any help?

My code is below.

namespace NinjectTestProject.Controllers
{

```
public interface ITest
{
    string Test();
}

public class Tester : ITest
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return "testing";
    }
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITest _test;

    public HomeController(ITest test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return Content(_test.Test());
    }

}
```

}

Service registration NinjectWebCommon

......

```
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Tester>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just found the way just this minute. I simple re-installed Ninject for MVC3 which somehow fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow the solution described in http://silesiaresearch.com/blog/BlogCSharp#Blog_20131204 Basically you need to extend `CreateKernel()` method with a custom `DependencyResolver`, meaning your `RegisteredServices()` method should work.

It did work on my website. However I shared a different reason for the same symptom. My binding were working fine, but MVC framework complained about missing default constructor in my controllers. It turns out that I missed installed NUGET component called `Ninject.Mvc3`

Answer (score 0):

Assembly attributes were absent for me:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
```